# Can you please make the captcha easier for humans?

Tags: feature-request, captcha

Hello, I am human, not a bot. Sometimes it is very hard for me to answer those captcha questions. Can you please use some other kind of question which would not require me to recognize letters?

Perhaps some simple logic questions?

Comment: How often are you seeing the captcha? If you have a registered account and a nominal rep, it should be pretty rare - I hardly ever see it...

Comment: It happens everyday at least one time / day...

Comment: What is wrong with you man/woman/person of indeterminate gender? What do you have against helping computers read books?

Comment: Keep in mind that you don't always have to be 100% accurate on these captchas. If you can't tell, odds are it's the less-well-known word pair, and your best guess will get past the captcha.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: if you edit your own post multiple times in short succession, the captcha comes up. I often get it.

Comment: Then don't do that?

Comment: "Can you please make the captcha easier for humans?" OK, but we'll make it much much harder for the robots. So you'll need to tell us which you are, and *no lying*! ;-p (OK, I'm in an odd mood...)

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I don't see why multiple edits in a short period of time is a problem.

Comment: About making it easier, the thing is, reCAPTCHA handles the CAPTCHAs, and it's highly unlikely that they'll make it easier for one specific site with problems.

Comment: The real problem is that the captcha is presented for stupid reasons, like I took to long to do my edit (uhh, because I stopped and *thought* about it... or I went to get a fresh cup of coffee, or someone came in to my office/called etc... or any of a number of things real humans do).

Comment: So if the robot fails the logic question, he must be a human?  =P

Answer (score 19):

Sometimes they're a bit tricky, but there's always the "give me another one" refresh button somewhere on the right hand side - I very rarely get more than two unreadable ones in a row.

Comment: sometimes it's not easy, e.g. nn and m, l0 and 1o, etc.

Comment: Because CAPTCHAs rely on visual perception, users unable to view a CAPTCHA (for example, due to a disability or because it is difficult to read) are unable to perform the task protected by a CAPTCHA.

Comment: @psihodelia: That's why there's a loudspeaker icon, so you can solve a sound captcha instead of a visual one.

Comment: but many people@job-place cannot use audio :)

Comment: @psihodelia: Not even with headphones, on the very rare occasions when you actually get asked for the CAPTCHA in the first place?

Comment: If Jon Skeet doesn't get bothered enough by captchas, then I really don't think it's a problem. He is after all, as close to the bot/human divide as any user of SO gets ;)

Comment: If you're visually impaired, and yet can't use audio in the workplace, how do you manage to work with a computer?

Comment: We're splitting hairs, here, as womble correctly points out. Let's not overthink everything. You can't cover all the edge cases, there has to be a point where the reward is just too small for the resources invested.

Comment: I think many people (including me) under-utilize the refresh captcha button

Answer (score 13):

If you come across any problems with parsing the text/visual option of the CAPTCHA screen, you can reload it.

Or, you can click on the speaker icon to hear a snippet of sound for the audio CAPTCHA option.

[image: captcha shot]

If you fail both options, you are a robot. Why is the turtle on its back?

Comment: see my comment to Jon Skeet above

Comment: No speakers allowed (use headphones) or no soundcard?

Comment: speakers are allowed, but it is soooo long - take headphones, listen... it is also hard for someone whos native language is not english

Comment: So you want an even harder CAPTCHA system, one that uses riddles?

Comment: I suspect a non-trivial *riddle* might be a problem for someone whose native language is not English.

Comment: Nice hair-do, random.

Comment: I think if you have enough ear hair that you can comb it, that it is time to trim.

Comment: "My mother?  Lemme tell you about my mother:" __[blammm]__

Answer (score 11):

Some actual data from our daily W3C web logs.

Out of a million plus hits in a given day, here's how many times the page `/captcha` was served by IIS:

```
/captcha      1,252
```

For context, one particular element we serve on a lot (but not all) pages was served up **716,582** times in the same time period.

The data simply doesn't support the argument that the captcha is coming up a lot for people.

Answer (score 5):

I'm having trouble parsing this.

It's difficult to read the letters, but doing a logic problem would be easier? The problem with logic problems (hah) is that you'd need to have a database of them. Lots of them. Or else there'd be enough repeats that a bot could still guess them.

I get the captcha every now and again, too; I also find it annoying. But making the letters hard to read is part of the point -- bots doing OCR will have difficulty with them, while humans (who have much fuzzier logic and are generally better at deriving meaning even from distorted shapes) will be able to make them out.

Comment: Emphasis on *fuzzier*.

Comment: Especially after a few drinks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you, or have you ever been, a machine?

Seriously, it used to annoy me a lot until I hit I guess 1000 rep. After that I hardly see it anymore. But it was annoying, not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There are other approaches to CAPTCHA that are much easier on people than those warped and distorted words. One called Confident CAPTCHA, for example, asks people to identify pictures of various things. It's very secure against bots, but a lot easier for most people to use. There are others that ask people to play a simple game, solve a riddle, draw a shape, etc. Websites should consider those alternatives when they're considering deploying a captcha on their site.