# New captcha suggestion

Tags: feature-request, captcha

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you please make the captcha easier for humans?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31004/can-you-please-make-the-captcha-easier-for-humans)

Why not to use such simple Captcha like this:

"I am Captcha and I will pick a secret word. You are user and you are to guess what word it is. If your guess is not right, I will give you a hint. You have only 3 attempts."

Then, interaction will be started and user will find this secret word in 3 attempts at most.

Example:
C(aptcha):Guess a word. It is red.
U(ser):Apple.
C:No. It is above.
U:Sun
C:Right!

Implementation:
questions = [..., ["sun":"It is red", "It is above", "It is celestial body"], ...]

Comment: I'm left wondering which planet you live on where the sun is red.

Comment: Krypton, obviously.  He's SUPERMAN!

Answer (score 4):

Captchas have been discussed before on Meta Stack Overflow.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=captcha

There never seems to be agreement on what would be an ideal captcha.

And why would there be?  What is obvious and trivial for one user might be difficult for others.

I think character recognition is about as close as we want to get to an *intelligence test* in the captcha.

Answer (score 3):

Bad idea.

- Easily broken: http://en.akinator.com/
- Someone has to type in all the questions.
- The average user would guess only about 2 to 3 times and then abandon the site because he's got it wrong. If the riddles are too simple it can be broken by a machine.

Comment: but maybe it is better than characters recognition ?