# Unreadable Captcha

Tags: feature-request, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you please make the captcha easier for humans?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31004/can-you-please-make-the-captcha-easier-for-humans)

This is a feature requst to please make your Human Verification more readable.

I'm a human :-P  and it usually takes me at least one mistake before I get a Captcha right.

The captcha's are really hard to read and I notice that I'm not the only one with this problem

I know that this is necessary but maybe instead you could ask a math problem with a simple answer? A lot of sites do that and if the problems are even simple computers can't make heads or tails of it.

In response to those who asked for an image :-)

*I'm supposed to type fractions now?*

[image]

*Or Hindi*

[image]

*What is that second word*

[image]

THIS JUST ISN'T small or localized its clearly happening across the site to a lot of people

Comment: SE can't do anything about it since they use a provider.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for clarification +1

Comment: I was going to suggest the audio captcha but it was horrible, as I just heard it for the first time today. :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you please make the captcha easier for humans?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31004/can-you-please-make-the-captcha-easier-for-humans) and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75965/the-recaptcha-has-become-too-difficult-for-humans-to-solve?lq=1

Comment: I came to this post fully expecting a screenshot of some hilariously unreadable captcha. I was very disappointed... :(

Comment: added an image :-)

Comment: Once, I got [a captch](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kkLrB.jpg) in [Hindi, the official language of India](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindi). I wrote it correct but still I got [an error](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rU26B.png). The meaning of that Hindi word is [*Pencil*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pencil) :)

Comment: Dude that's epic. Hindi Captcha.. Never seen that

Comment: @hims056 A hindi captcha ! That must be rare :)

Comment: @AshRj - Actually I feel myself lucky to get a captcha in Hindi :)

Comment: @hims056 That was what i was implying :)

Comment: @hims056 The Hindi one isnt even distorted

Comment: The second word is clearly wslany