# How to know if captcha character X is uppercase or lowercase

Tags: support, captcha

How can you see if captcha character X is uppercase or lowercase, because sometimes I can't figure it out.

Comment: Probably related/dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31004/can-you-please-make-the-captcha-easier-for-humans

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

Recaptcha is not case sensitive anyway.

I've never bothered with case and it is confirmed in [this response from Recaptcha support here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/recaptcha/F_mzZccdYGI).

That response is a few years old though. Trying the [online demo](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/demo/ajax) and typing in willfully the wrong case

[image]

this still showed up as "correct" after hitting "submit".